# How do you create a form without a new template that is submitted from the /show.html.erb page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this application where I'm trying to add dog family relations (dog A is sibling of dog B) using a pedigree table. However I'm having issues making the form that will make that happen. [This is how my form looks like at the moment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nfb5.jpg)

As you can see the form loads in a dog profile page, the user can pick one of his dogs and create the relation. This is the form code that renders in the views/dog/show.html.erb page from views/pedigrees/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@pedigree, url: new_pedigree_path, html: {method: :post}) do |d| %>
    Select your dog:
    <%= d.collection_select(:dog_id, @dogs,:id, :dname, :prompt => "Select your dog") %>
    <br>
    Select your dog relation to the dog from this profile:
    <%= select_tag(:relation_name, options_for_select([['Sibling', 1], ['Parent', 2], ['Grandparent', 3],
                                                       ['Great-grandparent', 4], ['Child', 5], ['Grandchild', 6], ['Great-grandchild', 7]])) %>
    <br>
    <%= d.submit 'Add Relation' %>
<% end %>
```

What I get in my generated source is the following:

```
 <form class="new_pedigree" id="new_pedigree" action="/pedigree/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="RYOjO10gUvVUQkRaqyum8wB0VJrTwm8MQ6WxIJ3eM4ukP2zHHDECFaT8UUYytSv2OGBUGhvK4k3fwOt+xDfabA==" />
```

When I click the button to submit the form I get the following error:

```
Missing template pedigree/new, application/new with...
```

How can I manipulate the form_for so that the pedigree relation is rendered without the need to have a new form template? And how can the #create method be called when the submit button is pressed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid hard-coding the `"/pedigrees"` url, the first line in your form partial should be

```
<%= form_for(@pedigree, url: pedigrees_path, html: {method: :post}) do |d| %>
```

You need to understand the difference between the `new` and `create` actions (and their associated routes/paths/urls). The `new_pedigree_path` is not the path that you use when you want to actually create a new record. (`new_pedigree_path` is just for fetching a form.) Instead, actually creating a new pedigree is done via a POST request to `pedigrees_path`.

```
                   Controller Action   HTTP Verb       Path Helper          Path
Get a form
for making a              new            GET          new_pedigree_path     /new_pedigree
new relationship 

Send data about
the new relationship     create          POST          pedigrees_path       /pedigrees
to the server; create
the new record.
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the hard coded /pedigrees to the path you had up there.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you're new, let me add some context.

---

You're currently invoking the form when on the `dogs#show` page. This does *not* mean you have to hardcode the `url` - passing the `@pedigree` variable should give Rails the information required to submit the form to `pedigrees#create`:

```
<%= form_for @pedigree do |d| %>
    Select your dog:
    <%= d.collection_select :dog_id, @dogs,:id, :dname, prompt: "Select your dog" %>

    Select your dog relation to the dog from this profile:
    <%= select_tag(:relation_name, options_for_select [['Sibling', 1], ['Parent', 2], ['Grandparent', 3],
                                                       ['Great-grandparent', 4], ['Child', 5], ['Grandchild', 6], ['Great-grandchild', 7]]) %>
    <%= d.submit 'Add Relation' %>
<% end %>
```

If you've got your `@pedigree` variable set, this should send the form to either `pedigrees#create` or `pedigrees#update` (depending on whether you set the variable with `Pedigree.new` or `Pedigree.find`).

Since you're calling the form through a partial, I would *highly* recommend using only *local* variables in it:

```
#app/controllers/dogs_controller.rb
class DogsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @dog = Dog.find params[:id]
      @pedigree = ...
   end
end

#app/views/dogs/show.html.erb
<%= render "pedigrees/form", locals: {pedigree: @pedigree} %>

#app/views/pedigrees/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for pedigree ...
```

This may seem inefficient to begin with, however you have to remember that [*partials*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) are meant to be available anywhere in your app. Using `@instance_variables` inside them is actually half way to an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)!

---

Some other notes:

**1. Never use HTML for "styling"**

I see people using `<br>` and `<p>` to create line breaks in HTML.

Although this "works", it's not correct. In fact, it's downright destructive (especially when you get to larger applications).

HTML *should* be treated as Markup (formatting **only**); CSS is what you need for styling:

```
<%= form_for @pedigree do |d| %>
   <%= d.text_field :name %>
   <%= d.text_field :type %>
<% end %>
```

This is how your HTML should look, you can then use the [following CSS to style it](http://jsfiddle.net/8kh0pn2c/):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
form input {
   display: block;
   margin: 3px 0;
}
```

If you need a line break for legitimate reasons (maybe you're using a list or something), then by all means, use `<br>` - but never use it to create the illusion of margin/padding.

For nothing else, it will mess up your styling with responsive interfaces etc.

-

**2. Many-To-Many**

I don't know your level of Rails, so apologies if this is too simplistic for you.

I believe you could improve this massively if you used a `many-to-many` relationship, specifically [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

[image]

```
#app/models/dog.rb
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pedigrees
   has_many :relations, through: :pedigrees
end

#app/models/pedigree.rb
class Pedigree < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :dog
   belongs_to :relation
end

#app/models/relation.rb
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pedigrees
   has_many :dogs, through: :pedigrees
end
```

This will allow you to populate `@dog.pedigrees` or `@dog.relations` from a single call. Thus, instead of having to `create` / `edit` new "pedigree" records, you'll be able to just work with `dog`:

```
#app/controllers/dogs_controller.rb
class DogsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @dog = Dog.find params[:id]
   end

   def update

   end

   private

   def dog_params
      params.require(:dog).permit(:name, :relation_ids)
   end
end
```

This would allow you to use the following:

```
#app/views/dogs/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @dog do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.collection_select :relation_ids, Relation.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This should allow you to pick the various "relations" your dog has, creating `Pedigree` records automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

I had to hard code the form_for

```
<%= form_for(@pedigree, url: "/pedigrees", html: {method: :post}) do |d| %>
```

I also made a mistake in my routes file. Instead of resources :pedigrees y had resources :pedigree.